# Shell Script: que hace esta salida

Tags: script, shell

```
 if grep ttt $i > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Hola @lethal_shooter Bienvenido!. Esta pregunta le falta mucha información todavía , el contexto , que haces y que haz entendido(por ejemplo) hasta el momento, no cuenta con todo para que te podamos ayudar , trata de editar tu pregunta y mostrarla ,hazlo antes de que cierren esta pregunta.

Comment: GREP  Usualmente, grep toma una expresión regular de la línea de comandos, lee la entrada estándar o una lista de archivos, e imprime las líneas que contengan coincidencias para la expresión regular.

Answer (score 1):

No está claro qué preguntas, pero si quieres decir "¿qué hace esta línea?":

```
if grep ttt $i > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

lo que está haciendo es ejecutar el comando `grep` para buscar el texto `ttt` en el fichero cuyo nombre está contenido en la variable `$i`, pero descarta lo que `grep` mostraría por pantalla (ya que el operador `>` está redirigiendo la salida estándar al pseudo-fichero `/dev/null`, que simplemente es un agujero negro que hace desaparecer todo lo que escribas en él, y el operador `2>` hace lo mismo con la salida de errores).

Aunque hayamos descartado la salida de `grep`, sin embargo, estamos usando su *exit status*, pues eso es lo que comprueba `if`. Si el *exit status* de `grep` es 0 (lo que indicaría que encontró coincidencias en el fichero), entonces la condición del `if` será cierta y se ejecutará el cuerpo de ese `if` (que no muestras, e iría entre un `then` y un `fi`). Si el *exit status* es distinto de cero, eso indica que `grep` no encontró coincidencias, y no se ejecuta el cuerpo del `if`.

Comment: Gracias por aportar pero es mejor esperar a que aclare y mejore la pregunta. Sobre todo para no promover indirectamente este tipo de preguntas de baja calidad. Un saludo